# C++: Callback handler to call object method

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I couldn't find any answers for this. I might be asking the wrong questions or using wrong keywords. Here's what I want to do.

I have a library that calls a callback handler with a fixed name.

```
int callbackHandler(int a);
void library (void)
{
  // receive data
  result = callbackHandler(data);
  // use result
}
```

and in my code, I create the handler like so

```
int callbackHandler(int a)
{
  int result;

  result = a*a;
  result += a;

  return result; 
}
```

I have a class method `myClass::myMath` that I would like the `callbackHandler` to use instead.

```
class myClass
{
  int myMath(int a);
}

int myClass::myMath(int a)
{
  int result;

  result = a*a;
  result += a;

  return result; 
}
```

Is there a better way to do this rather than to just call my class method from the callbackHandler?

Comment: `myMath` is a non-static member function. You need a `myClass` instance to call this function on. On which instance do you want to call it? Also what exactly do you mean with "better way"? What doesn't work or bothers you about your current approach (which you should fully show btw.)?

Comment: `library` is hardwired to call a function linked in called `callbackHandler`.  The only thing you can really do is have your implementatin of `callbackHandler` create an instance of `myClass` and invoke the myMath method off of that.  Otherwise, you could delcare the `myMath` method as static have have `callbackHandler` invoke `myClass::myMath` directly.

Comment: @walnut Ah okay. I will make `myMath` a static member function. Also because myClass will be create and will only have 1 instance of it.

Comment: @stephw If you never intend to have multiple instances of a class you should ask yourself whether it is supposed to be a class in the first place. If you just want to organize things belonging together, then C++ offers namespaces for that. On the other hand, don't limit your code unnecessarily. If it makes sense in principle to have multiple instances of the class, then work under the assumption that it can, even if it doesn't right now.

Comment: @walnut it's because I want to create an object that handles the read & write of static arrays as well as the callback functions that will also access those arrays. Is that the right idea to have? Or can I use a namespace for that as well?

Comment: @stephw There is not enough information to tell.

Comment: @selbie so if I declare `myMath` as static I can just invoke `myClass::myMath(a);` from `callbackHandler`?

Comment: @stephw - that would be correct.